# Numpy matmul over object data-type explanation

Tags: python, numpy

I am a bit confused when it comes to the operation of `numpy.matmul` over `dtype=object`.

Can someone explain how the following works? Particularly what is obtained in the last operation "total". I used this method (might be wrong) to replace matrix multiplication with loop iterations.

To give a rough idea what I am doing, the result of such calculation will be used to produce a 2 heat maps with the vertical being "z", horizontal being "g_in" and the color bars values would correspond each time to first/second element of values of "total". This is a dummy calculation for ABCD ray propagation with simultaneously variable distance "z" and input beam angle "g_in".

Code:

```
z = np.linspace(0, 10, 11) # distance
g_in = np.linspace(-5, 5, 11) #input angle
f_0, f_1 = 1, 1 #some constants

A = np.array([[1, z], [0, 1]], dtype = object)
B = np.array([[1, 0], [-1/(f_0), 1]], dtype = object)
C = np.array([[1, 2*f_0], [0, 1]], dtype = object)
D = np.array([[1, 0], [-1/(f_0), 1]], dtype = object)
E = np.array([[1, z], [0, 1]], dtype = object)
F = np.array([[1, 0], [-1/(f_1), 1]], dtype = object)
G = np.array([[1, f_1], [0, 1]], dtype = object)

H = np.matmul(G,F)
I = np.matmul(H,E)
J = np.matmul(I,D)
K = np.matmul(J,C)
L = np.matmul(K,B)

M = np.matmul(L, A)

print('Matrix M=',M)

col1 = np.empty((2, 1),dtype=object)
col1[:, 0] = [0, g_in]

print('Matrix col1[:,0]=',col1[:,0])

total = np.matmul(M, col1[:,0])

print('Matrix total=',total)

y_out = np.transpose(total[0].tolist())
g_out = np.transpose(total[1].tolist())

y_out_ = np.expand_dims(y_out, axis=0)
g_out_ = np.expand_dims(g_out, axis=0)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1,
ncols=1,sharex=True,sharey=True, figsize=(8, 6))
f1=ax1.imshow(y_out_, extent=  
[theta_in.min(),theta_in.max(),z_f.min(),z_f.max()],    
vmin=y_out_.min(),vmax=y_out_.max(), aspect="auto",
cmap='YlGnBu')
cb1=fig.colorbar(f1,orientation='vertical')
cb1.set_label(r'$y_{out}$',size=15)
ax1.set_ylabel(r'z', fontsize=20)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=20)
ax1.autoscale(tight=True)

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,sharex=True,figsize
(8, 6))
f2=ax2.imshow(g_out_, extent= 

[theta_in.min(),theta_in.max(),z_f.min(),z_f.max()],   

vmin=g_out_.min(),vmax=g_out_.max(), aspect="auto",
cmap='YlGnBu')
cb2=fig.colorbar(f2,orientation='vertical')
cb2.set_label(r'$g_{out}$',size=15)
ax2.set_xlabel(r' Angle, $θ_{in}$', fontsize=20)
ax2.set_ylabel(r'z', fontsize=20)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=20)
ax2.autoscale(tight=True)
```

The above code outputs:

[image]

Comment: With `object` dtype, it depends on the `+` and `*` operations of the elements.  It uses the same sort of sum-of-products that you would use when doing matrix multiplication by hand.  Speed with `object` dtype arrays tends to be the same as list comprehension calculations.  Show one or more of the results, so we can see what's happening without running the code ourselves.

Comment: `total` is the result of 3 `matmul`.  That's too many to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the size of `z`:

```
In [154]: z = np.linspace(0, 10, 5) # distance
     ...: g_in = np.linspace(-5, 5, 5) #input angle
     ...: f_0, f_1 = 1, 1 #some constants
     ...: 
In [155]: z
Out[155]: array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])
```

and just one pair of arrays:

```
In [156]: A = np.array([[1, z], [0, 1]], dtype = object)
     ...: B = np.array([[1, 0], [-1/(f_0), 1]], dtype = object)
In [157]: A
Out[157]: 
array([[1, array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])],
       [0, 1]], dtype=object)
In [158]: B
Out[158]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [-1.0, 1]], dtype=object)
```

Their matmul:

```
In [159]: A@B
Out[159]: 
array([[array([ 1. , -1.5, -4. , -6.5, -9. ]),
        array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])],
       [-1.0, 1]], dtype=object)
In [160]: _.shape
Out[160]: (2, 2)
```

this is the equivalent of:

```
In [162]: np.array([[1-1*z, 0+1*z],[0*1-1, 0+1]], object)
Out[162]: 
array([[array([ 1. , -1.5, -4. , -6.5, -9. ]),
        array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])],
       [-1, 1]], dtype=object)
```

All the other products are produced in the same way.

`col1` is a (2,1) with array element.  `E` is same as `A`.  The rest have numeric elements, and don't need to be object dtype.

In [166]: np.array([[0],[g_in]], object)
Out[166]:
array([[0],
[array([-5. , -2.5,  0. ,  2.5,  5. ])]], dtype=object)

`total` is structurally like

```
In [167]: B@A@col1[:,0]
Out[167]: 
array([array([ 0.  , -6.25,  0.  , 18.75, 50.  ]),
       array([ -5.  ,   3.75,  -0.  , -16.25, -45.  ])], dtype=object)
```

A (2,2)@(2,2)@(2,) => (2,), but with array elements.  Since the arrays have the same shape, it can be reduced to a numeric dtype:

```
In [171]: np.stack(Out[167])
Out[171]: 
array([[  0.  ,  -6.25,   0.  ,  18.75,  50.  ],
       [ -5.  ,   3.75,  -0.  , -16.25, -45.  ]])
```